# How to launch Screenshot by typing the PrintScreen key?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot

How do I change the behavior of the <kbd>PrntScrn</kbd>-key such that it launches the Screenshot application?

The default behavior for the <kbd>PrntScrn</kbd>-key on my computer is to take a screen shot of the whole screen, but I'd like Screenshot Application to launch so I can choose which part of the screen to capture.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Go to `System Settings` -> `Keyboard` -> `Shortcuts`

[image]

2. Choose `Custom` and click on the `+` sign.
3. You'll be requested to enter a command. Type this as a command: `screenshot-tool`.
4. Click on the `Disabled` string next to it.
5. Press your Print Screen button.

[image]

6. You'll get this dialog. Press the `Reassign` button.

[image]

Comment: after making the changes like what you told. i pressed print screen button but nothing happened to me'

Answer (score 1):

The default screenshot tool of elementary OS offers the possibility to record only a portion of the screen or just the current running app. Have a look at the keyboard options in the system settings. There is a section just for screenshots with all possible hotkeys.

Answer (score 1):

Follow @r3bl steps but use this command:

```
screenshot-tool --screen --clipboard
```

this will take a screenshot and save it to the clipboard too. These are all the options you can add:

```
--window    Capture active window
--area      Capture area
--screen    Capture the whole screen
--delay     Take screenshot after specified delay
--grab      Include the pointer with the screenshot
--redact    Redact system text
--clipboard Save screenshot to clipboard
```

Answer (score 1):

In Juno, there's a shortcut section for screenshots. It includes several shortcut options. Shift + PrintScreen lets you select an area to grab:

[image: screenshot shortcuts in juno]

(You can see from the screenshot I started with disabling the default shortcut, but I'm going to re-enable it, as the point in changing it was to get the functionality of the Shift + PrintScreen shortcut.)

Answer (score 0):

Go to *System settings* --> *Keyboard* --> add custom shortcut of `printscreen` select screenshot app and done.