# PrtScn not working natively

Tags: release-loki, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot

I have a Xiaomi Notebook Air, and my PrtScn Key do not work.

xinput test dont catch any event when I press PrtScn.

So i don't know if I can do something.
I'm asking for your help !
(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Okay, so that bug is know and we don't have any solution for the moment I think.

Comment: I'm afraid so. But you have a nice application for screenshots in elementary more complete than PrtScn. In any case, I'm also used to PrtScn and waiting for that bug to be solved.

Comment: I've found this workaround but haven't tried myself: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/712/how-to-launch-screenshot-by-typing-the-printscreen-key

Comment: I have tested but the bug is that the native touch is not reconized by xinput so ....
I can bind this to another key but that is not my objective (Currently I launch manualy gnome-screenshot)

Comment: Then the only solution is wait to see if the developers fix this in next upgrades. I could live without it but I'm used to the keyboard shortcut too.

Comment: yes that is not a big problem, I just want to know if the problem came from my keyboard or from the release.
xinput test do not show me anything, that's why I decided to post a question here, thinking the problem is my laptop